# Changing sql server service and sql server agent service startup account in SQL Server hosting SharePoint DB

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sql-server

i have a sharepoint deployment with one SQL Server (running on VM) hosting the config DB and another SQL Server (Physical Host because VM was running out of space) to host the huge Content DBs. I need to schedule automatic backups of the Content DBs to a network share. For that i need to run the SQL Server Service with an account having permissions to the share as suggested in https://support.microsoft.com/kb/207187?wa=wsignin1.0

I tried changing the logon as a service account to a domain account which has permissions to the Network Share and is also in local Administrators group of SQL Server and has "public and sysadmin" roles in SQL Server but that caused an issue. the SharePoint Web Application started showing a White Screen so I had to revert back to the default accounts i.e. NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT and NT Service\MSSQLSERVER. I viewed the event logs . These are the types of error i got after changing the logon as a service account to a domain account

**1) Information Rights Management (IRM): Retried too many times to initialize IRM client. Cannot retry more. Retried times is:0x5.**

- System
- Provider
  [ Name] Microsoft-SharePoint Products-SharePoint Foundation
  [ Guid] {6FB7E0CD-52E7-47DD-997A-241563931FC2}
  **EventID   5148
  Version 15
  Level   2
  Task    9**
  **Opcode    0**
  Keywords    0x4000000000000000
- TimeCreated
  [ SystemTime]   2015-02-02T04:46:04.750899500Z
  EventRecordID   176477
- Correlation
  [ ActivityID]   {8FACE59C-1E17-50D0-7135-25FDB824CDBE}
- Execution
  [ ProcessID]    6912
  [ ThreadID] 8872
  Channel Application
  Computer
- Security
  [ UserID]   S-1-5-21-876248814-3204482948-604612597-111753
- EventData
  hex0    0x5

**2) Unknown SQL Exception 0 occurred. Additional error information from SQL Server is included below.**

The target principal name is incorrect.  Cannot generate SSPI context.

- System
- Provider
  [ Name] Microsoft-SharePoint Products-SharePoint Foundation
  [ Guid] {6FB7E0CD-52E7-47DD-997A-241563931FC2}
  **EventID   5586
  Version 15
  Level   2
  Task    3
  Opcode  0**
  Keywords    0x4000000000000000
- TimeCreated
  [ SystemTime]   2015-02-02T07:01:35.843757700Z
  EventRecordID   176490
- Correlation
  [ ActivityID]   {50B4E59C-5E3A-50D0-7135-22AD91909F02}
- Execution
  [ ProcessID]    6912
  [ ThreadID] 5452
  Channel Application
  Computer
- Security
  [ UserID]   S-1-5-17
- EventData
  int0    0
  string1 The target principal name is incorrect. Cannot generate SSPI context.

Answer (score 0):

The service account doesn't matter for SharePoint so you're probably better off looking into this as a SQL Server issue. After changing the service account, did you try querying the databases through Management Studio to make sure they were still accessible?

This is a steb-by-step of how to change the SQL Server accounts: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345578.aspx use the Version drop down for your SQL Version

and this describes all the permissions that are configured during the Installation process (and I think this is where something went wrong):
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143504.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219062.aspx